# How to pass Javascript variable with form on submit?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I want to pass a variable created with Javascript to $form_state so that I can use this variable in the form_submit function.

In an ajaxified form I can use:

```
Drupal.ajax[ajax_el].options.data._my_vars = JSON.stringify(js_object);
```

But how can I accomplish it in a non ajax form? Is there another possibility than using a hidden field? It might be possible to pass it to a field with `#access => FALSE`?

I would welcome every advice. Many thanks!

Daniel

Comment: You can `#attach` JS settings. This is how the `#states` data get passed during Ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In which way I have to attach the settings? I just know the the way to pass a variable to the client and not vice versa:
`$form['#attached']['js']['my_key'] = array(
  'data' => array('my_key' => $settings),
  'type' => 'setting'
);`. How can I pass a variable generated with JS to the server with the settings?

Comment: Oops sorry I though about this the other way.

Comment: No problem! But you probably don't have another idea for my problem? :)

Comment: You could use a hidden field, which is JS and css independent. You can use javascript place a cookie, which will be submitted with every http request thereafter until cleared. Hidden fields seems to be the way to go.

Comment: is there a way to run js before the form values are sent to the server, so that I can fill the hidden field with the variable?

Comment: ok, that was easy: `$form['#attributes']['onsubmit'] = array('javascript: some_function();');`. That's inline indeed, but I think it's ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a field for that variable, like this:

```
$form['_my_vars'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#default_value' => $_my_vars);
```

Whenever you are changing variable, update field's value.

**Do not** use

```
'#access' => FALSE
```

The [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access) clarifies it:

> when FALSE, the element is not rendered and the user submitted value is not taken into consideration.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I already worked it out with the help of AyeshK. See the comments of my question. But nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: @user3083978 Comments may get purged without notice. If AyeshK wrote this first, I can delete my answer. But only *after* his answer is posted as actual **answer**.